# Unwanted darkening at polygon edges when using normal maps with SSAO

Tags: directx, hlsl, ssao

I'm using a SSAO alghorithm called "SAO", seen here: [Scalable Ambient Obscurance](https://web.archive.org/web/20170816185443/http://graphics.cs.williams.edu/papers/SAOHPG12/).

I'm currently having issues with "smooth" normals, for example when using normal/height maps.

To give an example, here is the SAO and the normals for a chair rendered with "raw" normals, i.e not using the accompanied normal map:

[image: sao1]

[image: normal1]

Looks pretty OK overall.

now.. when I apply the chair's normal map:

[image: sao2]

[image: normal2]

What could be wrong? Is there anything obvious wrong with the normals?

I'm using the SAO shader, with only very minor changes. The normal/position textures are in world space, and then converted to view space. I know this is not optimal, but for the sake of the alghorithm it should not matter.

```
#ifndef SSAO_PIXEL_HLSL
#define SSAO_PIXEL_HLSL

#include "Constants.h"
#include "Common.hlsl"

static const float gNumSamples = 11.0;
static const float gRadius = 0.2;
static const float gRadius2 = gRadius * gRadius;
static const float gProjScale = 500.0;
static const float gNumSpiralTurns = 7;
static const float gBias = 0.01;
static const float gIntensity = 1.0;


cbuffer SSAOCBuffer : register(CBUFFER_REGISTER_PIXEL)
{
    float4x4 gViewProjMatrix;
    float4x4 gProjMatrix;
    float4x4 gViewMatrix;
    float2 gScreenSize;
};

Texture2D gPositionTexture : register(TEXTURE_REGISTER_POSITION);
Texture2D gNormalTexture : register(TEXTURE_REGISTER_NORMAL);
SamplerState gPointSampler : register(SAMPLER_REGISTER_POINT);


float3 reconstructNormal(float3 positionWorldSpace)
{
    return normalize(cross(ddx(positionWorldSpace), ddy(positionWorldSpace)));
}

/** Read the camera - space position of the point at screen - space pixel ssP + unitOffset * ssR.Assumes length(unitOffset) == 1 */
float3 getOffsetPosition(int2 ssC, float2 unitOffset, float ssR) {
    // Derivation:
    //  mipLevel = floor(log(ssR / MAX_OFFSET));

    // TODO: mip levels
    int mipLevel = 0; //TODO: clamp((int)floor(log2(ssR)) - LOG_MAX_OFFSET, 0, MAX_MIP_LEVEL);

    int2 ssP = int2(ssR*unitOffset) + ssC;

    float3 P = gPositionTexture[ssP].xyz;

    P = mul(gViewMatrix, float4(P, 1.0)).xyz;

    return P;
}

float2 tapLocation(int sampleNumber, float spinAngle, out float ssR)
{
    // Radius relative to ssR
    float alpha = float(sampleNumber + 0.5) * (1.0 / gNumSamples);
    float angle = alpha * (gNumSpiralTurns * 6.28) + spinAngle;

    ssR = alpha;
    return float2(cos(angle), sin(angle));
}

float sampleAO(uint2 screenSpacePos, float3 originPos, float3 normal, float ssDiskRadius, int tapIndex, float randomPatternRotationAngle)
{
    float ssR;
    float2 unitOffset = tapLocation(tapIndex, randomPatternRotationAngle, ssR);
    ssR *= ssDiskRadius;

    // The occluding point in camera space
    float3 Q = getOffsetPosition(screenSpacePos, unitOffset, ssR);

    float3 v = Q - originPos;

    float vv = dot(v, v);
    float vn = dot(v, normal);

    const float epsilon = 0.01;
    float f = max(gRadius2 - vv, 0.0); 
    
    return f * f * f * max((vn - gBias) / (epsilon + vv), 0.0);
}

float4 ps_main(float4 position : SV_Position) : SV_Target0
{
    uint2 screenSpacePos = (uint2)position.xy;

    float3 originPos = gPositionTexture[screenSpacePos].xyz;
    originPos = mul(gViewMatrix, float4(originPos, 1.0)).xyz;
    float3 normal = gNormalTexture[screenSpacePos].xyz;//reconstructNormal(originPos);
    normal = mul(gViewMatrix, float4(normal, 0.0)).xyz;

    // Hash function used in the HPG12 AlchemyAO paper
    float randomPatternRotationAngle = (3 * screenSpacePos.x ^ screenSpacePos.y + screenSpacePos.x * screenSpacePos.y) * 10;
    float ssDiskRadius = -gProjScale * gRadius / originPos.z;

    float ao = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < gNumSamples; i++)
    {
        ao += sampleAO(screenSpacePos, originPos, normal, ssDiskRadius, i, randomPatternRotationAngle);
    }

    float temp = gRadius2 * gRadius;
    ao /= temp * temp;

    float A = max(0.0, 1.0 - ao * gIntensity * (5.0 / gNumSamples));

    return A;
}

#endif
```

EDIT: update, using reconstructNormals() to reconstruct normals - for simpler models it looks okay (the chair) but the more advanced models like the alien looks really bad/blocky. Any way to fix this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: In general you should use geometry normal and not normalmap for SSAO.

Comment: Why is that? I havn't found any sources on that. Also, the model importer I use, assimp (http://assimp.sourceforge.net/), has an option to calculate "smooth" normals, with the same result as using a normal map. Are these not considered geometry normals?

Comment: No, smooth normals are calculated by averaging triangle normals attached to a vertex. What you need is the actual triangle normals, which in your shader is calculated in the reconstructNormal() function. You need the actual geometry normals because SSAO is calculated using depth samples in depth buffer and their relation to given pixel. Using wrong normal will result wrong weighting for the samples, e.g. think of a depth sample on the same geometry plane as the pixel whose SSAO you are calculating.

Comment: reconstructed normals looks really jagged/blocky on some advanced models, edited first post. Is it really viable to use that?

Comment: Looks wrong that convex shape (head) has self-occlusion along the polygon edges. Could it be that your cross product in reconstructNormal() is wrong way around?

Comment: Crytek actually even uses normal maps for their SSAO. So it definitely is possible!

Comment: it is possible but you'll get more self-occlusion because the normal (of the map) is transformed near to the geo (=depth) surface, and therefore more samples are occluded - if the normalmap would be real geometry instead, that pixel would be further away from the geo, but it isn't because normalmaps are not reflected in the depthbuffer.
To clarify: In Geo, the normal points away from the surface. With NormalMappings, the Normal of a pixel may be almost perpendicular to the surface and if you align your hemisphere for sao at that normal, half the samples may be occluded. result: more black.

Comment: @JarkkoL if you're still around and want to post your comments as an answer, I'd upvote it to stop the Community bot from continually bumping this old question. 

Answer (score 0):

I'm not the expert to answer this question, but perhaps:

Points on your detailed normal map are skewing some of your offset samples back into the geometry?

The details on your normal map contain dark spots/crevices, which are being read by the shader as corners?